# Centos 7 Docker container with Apache, having issue with reverse proxy

Tags: docker, apache, proxy, centos7, reverse

I am trying to have container use reverse proxy
so instead of having to visit localhost:92
I can visit localhost/

I am getting the following error in httpd

```
[proxy:error] [pid 14] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:92 (localhost) failed
[proxy:error] [pid 14] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 0s
```

here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  php:
    container_name: jobs-php
    networks:
      dominion_net:
        ipv4_address: 15.16.235.5
    hostname: jobs
    domainname: jobs.test
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "92:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
networks:
  dominion_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "15.16.235.0/24"
        - subnet: "2001:3984:3989::/64"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y install deltarpm
RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install \
    epel-release \
    httpd \
    httpd-tools \
    unzip ksh zip unzip \
    yum-utils nano which wget epel-release  httpd-devel  \
    && yum groupinstall -y 'Development tools'

RUN yum install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

RUN yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php80 php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql \
    php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo  php-xdebug  php-pear php-devel php-sockets php-mbstring\
    php80-php-oci8

RUN yum -y install mod_proxy_uwsgi mod_proxy_html
RUN yum install -y supervisor beanstalkd iproute xclip zsh net-tools

RUN mkdir -p /etc/httpd/sites-enabled
RUN chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html

COPY docker/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
COPY docker/apache.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 92

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

apache.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log combined

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteEngine On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:92/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:92/


</VirtualHost>
```

here is list of loaded modules

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_uwsgi_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 allowmethods_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_dbd_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_socache_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_dbd_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 data_module (shared)
 dbd_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 dumpio_module (shared)
 echo_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 remoteip_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_plain_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 socache_dbm_module (shared)
 socache_memcache_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
 lua_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bybusyness_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 lbmethod_bytraffic_module (shared)
 lbmethod_heartbeat_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
 xml2enc_module (shared)
 systemd_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 php_module (shared)
```

I have googled this, and found a bunch of answers saying selinux is causing issue, but I do not have selinux on.
Not sure what to try next.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: In your compose file you have ports "92:80". So you are binding your container port 80 to host port 92. In this case you'll always have to use http://localhost:92/, no matter what you do in the container, reverse proxies or not. Why not just use port 80 (ports "80:80") ? The reported errors suggest there isn't any server listening on port 92, why is that port even considered ? I'm probably missing something

Comment: I am aware I can use port 80, I do not want to. I want multiple containers, with each one being accessible from just the ip address without having to use ports at all